# Chatting Icon for boldchat softeware

Tags: html

I'm using this tip to integrate BoldChat to my Website .It shows an icon with the current  status (available, away and so on). I want to change these images. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

My name is Dave and I am a member of Bold Software's support team. I wanted to let you know that the images can be change within the client user interface. To accomplish this, login to the Bold Software client interface and navigate to **Setup > Account Setup > Chat > Custom Chat Buttons**. Select the chat button definition associated to the code and then choose edit. The edit dialog will expose both the available and unavailable url designations. You can use your own by supplying image url's or choose images from the available gallery of images.

Once thing to keep in mind, the code has an embedded association to the chat button definition, this enables you to dynamically change the related images without having to re-implement the HTML chat code. It is possible to change the image out via a straight code edit but you will give up the before mention flexibility as well as the dynamic display of the available/unavailable image presentation based on your operators availability.

Please feel free to contact me or one of my analysts, we be be happy to assist you with any further questions.

Dave Hammer
Bold Software Support
Technical Services Manager
316.630.9933 option 2
support@boldchat.com
@BoldSupport

Comment: Don't know anything about the product, and, honestly, I haven't even read the question - but +1 because it's nice to see a company watching StackOverflow for questions about their products.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this script before myself, but you can check the 'images' folder (or similar) of the script and see if the image you want to modify/replace is located there, if it is, simply replace it.

Another way of locating images is 'inspecting' the element (the image you want to replace) with a web browser, such as Google Chrome. There will be a direct link to the image file in the website's source, or it will be referenced as an image in a css file. If this is the case, you may or may not be able to change the image, as some css files reference to sprites, which can be a pain to edit...